# Display JSON data into UILabel in swift 3.0 ?

Tags: json, swift3, uilabel, xcode8

How to display JSON data into UILabel in Swift 3.0 ?

I have these **three (3)** UILabel named **login,email** and **pw**

Right now i managed to display the JSON in output section but i don't know how to display that JSON data into UILabel.

Here's my **JSON data**

```
[
    {"login":"ID001","pw":"123","email":"first@p.com"},
    {"login":"ID002","pw":"456","email":"second@p.com"}
]
```

And my **viewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var login: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var email: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var pw: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/get.php")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {
            (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Error")
            }
            else {
                if let content = data {
                    do { 
                        let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
                        print(myJSON)
                    }
                    catch {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your print(myjson) is to append another array and those array pass in label its simple .

Answer (score 0):

You can decode your json data like that.

```
do {
            if let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [[String:Any]] {
                print(json)
                for jsonDictionary in myJSON {
                    print(jsonDictionary["login"]!)
                    print(jsonDictionary["pw"]!)
                    print(jsonDictionary["email"]!)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Something went wrong")
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . But how to make UILabel display those JSON data. can you update your answer ? Thanks.

Comment: You mean, how to create UILabel programmatically or set data UILabel text programmatically ?